# Можно ли скомпилировать py файл в exe, но через код

Tags: python, компиляция, pip, pyinstaller, модули

Моя задача сделать скомпилированный Python скрипт, который будет по шаблону создавать код и его компилировать (тоже в exe). Обычно пользуюсь PyInstaller, но не представляю как запустить компиляцию PyInstaller на ПК, на котором нет Python и PIP

Comment: Сперва установить Python и PIP, а затем запустить PyInstaller ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: имелось ввиду данное: допустим, у нас есть клиент (который не имеет Python и PIP), которому я скину программу, а программа должна уметь самостоятельно компилировать .py файлы.Короче внутри программы должен быть компилятор Python.

Comment: @LEANX т.е. у него не развернут питон и пип, но у него откуда не пойми есть исходники ?

Comment: @LEANX И эти манипуляции проще, чем установить питон? Есть кстати такой виндовый портативный дистрибьютив питона https://winpython.github.io/#portable

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать виртуальную среду питон и импортировать туда `pyinstaller` и остальные модули нужные для скрипта и запускать `pyinstaller` через батник но не забудте открыть виртуальную среду в батнике

Comment: Для создания виртуальной среды на компьютере должен быть установленный питон, а это противоречит условию вопроса

Comment: ему нужен скрипт который може компилировать другие скрипты и который можно запустить на компе без питона